# Java logger to archive previous set of logs

Tags: java, logging, log4j, shutdown

I have a Java application and would like to store off 'the logs as they were when the application later terminated' in order to debug possible shutdown issues.  The logic I have in mind is:

- Create my own logger class based on log4j
- Override activateOptions() to save off the files before logging starts
- Leave everything else the same.

But that raises some questions:

- Is activateOptions() the correct place for this logic?
- Is there an equivalent of activateOptions() in basic Java logging or must I go with log4j?
- Is there a better way that I've not yet discovered?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JordiCastilla when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: Interesting.  Is there a 'statement' somewhere is what sorts of questions StackExchange might like asked on stackOverflow and which on programmers....?